# Angular2. A way to assign a local template variable to each element in the list

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple piece of code like

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of list">
    <div class="button">Click to show text</div>
    <div class="text">hello</div
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to create and assign a local variable isVisible to each and every hello div so that when you click on .button, only one text div will be shown. I tried to do it like so

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of list">
    <div class="button" (click)="isVisible ? isVisible = false : isVisible = true">Click to show text</div>
    <div *ngIf="isVisible" class="text">hello</div
  </li>
</ul>
```

But when clicking on .button, every single .text div gets shown. Is there a similar way to do it right?

I know there is a way to do this by assigning an extra isVisible boolean to every item before I even show it but I am currently looking for other ways of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers work if you want only one item at a time to be visible but fail if you want multiple items visible, to achieve multiple items visible, you can just set a property on the objects you're iterating over:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of list">
    <div class="button" (click)="item.isVisible ? item.isVisible = false : item.isVisible = true">Click to show text</div>
    <div *ngIf="item.isVisible" class="text">hello</div
  </li>
</ul>
```

the drawback here is that you're introducing a new property onto your objects that you may not want.  Making a new component that holds the property for you is a more complete solution, but may be overkill depending on the situation.

Comment: Ye looks like I don't have a choice. I didn't know you could do this in the html template. I thought i'd have to assign the isVisible variable in the ts file. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a temporary variable on the html code, instead I would have a variable on the component like currentItemIndex, something like this:

```
@Component()
export class SomeComponent {
    currentItemIndex: number;
    onClick(itemIndex) {
        this.currentItemIndex = itemIndex;
    }
}
```

And in the component html:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index">
   <div class="button" (click)="onClick(i)">Click to show text</div>
    <div *ngIf="currentItemIndex === i" class="text">hello</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index">
 <div class="button" (click)="setIndex(i); isVisible=!isVisible">Click to show 
  text</div>
 <div *ngIf="isVisible && (currentIndex === i)" class="text">hello</div
</li>
```

and in your component

```
setIndex(index){
   this.currentIndex = index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new component that takes care of the click.

The new component can have an **@Input** variable that gets the item from the ngIf and takes care of everything.

```
<ul>
  <li *ngIf="let item of list">
   <new_component [item]="item"></new_component>
  </li>
</ul>
```

template for new component

```
<div class="button" (click)="isVisible ? isVisible = false : isVisible = true">Click to show text</div>
<div *ngIf="isVisible" class="text">hello</div>
```